# Android WorkManager getting reference to Worker class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

I'm facing following problem: there's my class which inherits `CoroutineWorker`. Logic of this worker is complicated enough, in fact `doWork()` calls bunch of other routines inside and catches (`collect`) results of several `StateFlow`s, like:

```
   override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
      //blah-blah
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            _scanResultState.collectLatest {
                //blah-blah
            }
        }
      return ...
   }
```

**Questions:**

1. Can I somehow return/put collected `StateFlow` values (values are simple primitive objects) to `Worker.Result`?
2. Or as an option - how could I listen/collect those `StateFlow` in other class - outside of my `Worker`?

Since, `Worker` class instantiated by `WorkManager` - I can't have a reference to concrete instance of `Worker`. E.g. in `Service` I could have reference to instance [through bound Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services), but in case of WorkManager looks like it's impossible.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1. If the values are primitive, you can put them in `Data` when returning the Work Result. 2. Use a foreground service if this is a long-running UI based task or as the below answer suggests, use Room.

Comment: How can I return a value from inside of 'collect'? I tried but couldn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to share a flow from your Worker class to your app, you can use room database for that, for example let's say that you want to share a Flow<List> from your `Worker` to achieve that you need to follow these steps:

1. First create a `Book Entity` in your room database.
2. Second add a function in your `Dao` that returns a Flow<List>.
3. Third collect that flow in your app (view model, repository, fragment...).
4. Finally in your `Worker` keep adding books to your room database.

With these 4 steps you will be able to collect data from `Worker` in any other class.

I hope that my answer was clear and helpful :D

Comment: Looks workable, but ugly :) I'd prefer to have more nice solution

Comment: That's the only way to do it :D, and in some cases when you need to keep that data in room database it's a good solution.

Comment: Maybe, `DataStore` would be more feasible?

Comment: Well, if you just want to share a boolean or int or any simple type, DataStore is more feasible but if you want to share an object or a list of an object you can't do it with DataStore.